# Set custom post default language

Tags: wordpress, default, wpml, podscms

Set custom post default language.
I created a custom post with pods and I have WPML plugin installed. 
I want to show this custom post only in a language which is not the default one of the website so that the urls will be http://example.com/en/postname instead of http://example.com/postname.
For this I would like when i create a new post of these custom posts that their default language should be english and not the default language of the website.
Otherwise I have every time to change the default language of the post for each post.
How can i set another default language for the custom post than the one of the website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress custom post language WPML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166165/wordpress-custom-post-language-wpml)

Comment: You can change it for the specific site. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131678/how-to-get-posts-in-different-language-from-wpml-plugin

Comment: But i need the url to be /en/postname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_english_halacha');

function my_english_halacha($post_id) {
$post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

switch( $post_type )
{
case 'english_halacha':
     $set_language_args = array(
        'element_id'    => $post_id,
        'element_type'  => 'post_english_halacha',
        'language_code'   => 'en',
        'rewrite'           => array('slug' => ( (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en') ) ),
        'source_language_code' => 'he',


    );
global $sitepress;

$sitepress->switch_lang('en');
    do_action( 'wpml_set_element_language_details', $set_language_args );




break;

  case 'spanish_halacha':
     $set_language_args = array(
        'element_id'    => $post_id,
        'element_type'  => 'post_spanish_halacha',
        'language_code'   => 'es',
        'rewrite'           => array('slug' => ( (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='es') )       ),
        'source_language_code' => 'he',


    );
global $sitepress;

 $sitepress->switch_lang('es');
    do_action( 'wpml_set_element_language_details', $set_language_args );




break;
  } 

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following action to functions.php, and I hope Problem will be Solved:

```
function update_post_language( $post_id ) {
$post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
if ($post_type == 'dwqa-question' || $post_type == 'dwqa-answer') {
    $term = term_exists('ar', 'language');
    if ($term !== 0 && $term !== null`enter code here`) {
        wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array ('ar'), 'language', true );
    }
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_post_language' );
```

Comment: I followed your code but it is not working function update_post_language( $post_id ) {
$post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
if ($post_type == 'english_halacha') {
    $term = term_exists('en', 'language');
    if ($term !== 0 && $term !== null) {
        wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array ('en'), 'language', true );
    }
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_post_language' );